# how to set background xml file in drawable for a view?

Tags: android, xml, background, syntax-error, drawable

how can I set an xml background file that placed in drawable for a view without using `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` ?

for example I created a drawable xml file for my textview

when I call `TV.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_pic_back));` eclipse automatically add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` at the first of my function.

how can I use that without `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` ?

Comment: did you try setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tv_pic_back) because setBackground is implemented in api level 16

Comment: you are right, but I saying use setBackgroundResource which will work as setBackgroundDrawable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a class where I put a lot of code to handle the different APIs, so that you use one line of code for one API, and another line of code for another API.

```
public static void setBackgroundDrawable(View view, Drawable drawable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
    else {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

This will still give you a warning because `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated, but if you instead would use `setBackground(drawable)` for all versions then your application would crash on API levels lower than Jelly Bean (API 16).

However, in your case all you need to do is actually `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tv_pic_back);` because you don't need to get the drawable from the resource id yourself, Android will do that for you if you give it your resource id when you call the right method.

The [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) will tell you which methods are deprecated and which methods are implemented in which API version.